# Cannot pass MichelsonMap as smart contract method parameter

Tags: taquito

I have the following smartPy code deployed to a contract:

```
@sp.entry_point
def add(self, id, data_raw):
    sp.set_type(id, sp.TString)
    sp.set_type(data_raw, sp.TMap(sp.TString, sp.TString))
    
    self.data.mapping[id] = sp.record(
        data = data_raw,
    )
```

Now I want to call this contract with Taquito like this:

```
const id = "test_id"
const storageMap = MichelsonMap.fromLiteral({
    "1": "Test",
    "2": "Test2"
})

return tezos.wallet.at(accountSettings.contractAddress)
    .then((contract) => {
        reportResult("Sending...", "info", "#result-bar");
        return contract.methods.add(id, storageMap).send();
    })
    .then((op) => {
        reportResult("Waiting for confirmation...", "info", "#result-bar");
        return op.confirmation(1).then(() => op.hash);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        reportResult(error.message, "error", "#result-bar");
    });
```

But I get the error `[data_raw] Value must be a MichelsonMap`. Is there an issue with me passing the MichelsonMap to a contract entry point? I see this is viable [here](https://tezostaquito.io/docs/smartcontracts#choosing-between-the-methods-or-methodsobject-members-to-interact-with-smart-contracts), but I cannot see the contract example.

Edit 1:
This is what I get when `console.log(storageMap)`
[image]

Comment: What do you get when you `console.log(storageMap)`?

Comment: @ClaudeBarde Added a picture of the console,log return.

Comment: I don't understand why you would have an error in Taquito about `data_raw` when that variable doesn't appear in your JavaScript code, but only in your SmartPy code. Did you leave other parts of your JS code out?

Comment: @ClaudeBarde I left out the dependencies and connection to wallet. It's mostly the sample code from beacon. The error I get is from the `catch` block. I supposed it came from the smart contract entry point itself? I don't have `data_raw` anywhere else in my JS code.

Comment: Can you try to pass an empty map with `new MichelsonMap()` and let me know how it goes?

Comment: @ClaudeBarde I've tried that, but unfortunately get the same error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134831/discussion-between-claude-barde-and-user8188).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [michelson-sdk (Taquito example)](https://romarq.github.io/michelson-sdk/taquito) to generate the Michelson values (Micheline or Michelson JSON).

**You want something like this:**

```
import { Record, String, Map } from "@tezwell/michelson-sdk/literal";

const storage = Record({
  id: String("test_id"),
  data_raw: Map([
    [String("1"), String("Test")],
    [String("2"), String("Test2")]
  ])
});

console.log("Michelson JSON: ", storage.toJSON());
```

Comment: After trying for hours to run this package with parceljs, it actually doesn't work, and gives me the same error

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the main problem was in SmartPy inverting the parameters of my generated method. So while I defined the following method:

```
add(id, storageMap)
```

On chain it was generated as

```
add(storageMap, id)
```

I'm not sure if that's a SmartPy bug or is by design, but what I called in Taquito and worked is this:

```
return contract.methods.add(storageMap, id).send();
```